# Hand region extraction and distinguish it from face

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

Right now I'm working on a system which can recoginize human hand gesture and execute corresponding orders. However, I have some troubles in locating and hand and ruling out the influence of the face region due to the colour similarity between hand and face.
Therefore, I need a robust algorithm to locate the hand region more accurately and stably. Can anyone give me some advices on it?

By the way, there is another small question: if the resulted hand region in a binary picture is full of holes, how can I efficiently fill the holes so that I can find the correct coutour of the hand?

Comment: what if the person in the picture wears gloves?

Comment: Show some pictures if you will

Answer (score 0):

First, as used in opencv for detecting faces, you can train a [Haarcascade](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html) classifier ([Adaboost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost)) for detecting hands. You should build a training database with lots of hands images.

Second, fill holes in binary picture should be solve using [dilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_%28morphology%29) operator (morphology).